# Stationary types are almost orthogonal if and only if the realizers are independent

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory

Model theory Wiki (https://modeltheory.fandom.com/wiki/Orthogonal_types_(stability_theory)) states that stationary types are almost orthogonal if and only if the realizers are independent.  It does not provide a proof, which it says is "easy."  I attempted to do this myself just by the axioms of the independence relation, but my proof remains incomplete.  I have Pillay's *Introduction to Stability Theory* and Tent and Zigler's *A Course in Model Theory*, but I don't think they contain a proof of this fact.

How can one prove this?  Alternatively: is there a source from which to learn the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(x)$ and $q(y)$ be types over $C$. Assume that $p(x)$ is stationary and that for all $a$ realizing $p(x)$ and $b$ realizing $q(y)$, we have $a \downarrow_C b$ (here I'm using $\downarrow$ in place of the independence anchor). We would like to show that $p(x)$ and $q(y)$ are almost orthogonal, which means that there is a unique complete type extending $p(x)\cup q(y)$.

So let $ab$ and $a'b'$ be two realizations of $p(x)\cup q(y)$. Since $\text{tp}(b/C) = \text{tp}(b'/C) = q(y)$, there is some automorphism $\sigma\in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathcal{U}/C)$ with $\sigma(b') = b$. Let $a'' = \sigma(a')$. By our hypothesis, $a\downarrow_C b$ and $a'\downarrow_C b'$, so by invariance of $\downarrow_C$, we have $a''\downarrow_C b$. Further, $\text{tp}(a/C) = \text{tp}(a'/C) = \text{tp}(a''/C) = p(x)$, and since $p(x)$ is stationary, $\text{tp}(a/Cb) = \text{tp}(a''/Cb)$. Hence $\text{tp}(ab/C) = \text{tp}(a''b/C)$. We have $\sigma^{-1}(a''b) = a'b'$, so  $\text{tp}(ab/C) = \text{tp}(a'b'/C)$. We've shown that any two realizations of $p(x)\cup q(y)$ have the same type over $C$, so $p(x)\cup q(y)$ has a unique completion.

Note that we only needed to assume that $p(x)$ was stationary, $q(y)$ can be an arbitrary type. And the proof works just as well (using symmetry of $\downarrow$) if only $q(y)$ is assumed to be stationary.

---

Regarding a reference: You're right that Pillay doesn't prove this in *Introduction to Stability Theory*, but he does state it twice (Exercise 8.45 and Note 9.30), leaving the proof to the reader. The statement also appears as Exercise 10.2.2 in Tent & Ziegler and as Exercise VI.1.27 in Baldwin's *Fundamentals of Stability Theory*. It seems the consensus among authors is that the proof is a good exercise!

Comment: You're helpful as ever.  For the other direction, one invokes the existence property of the independence relation, I'm assuming?

Comment: @Pteromys Exactly. The types can be realized independently over $C$, and any two realizations have the same type over $C$, so any realizations are independent over $C$. Note that we don't need any stationarity hypothesis here.